# How to find optimum of a function with a few known points?

Tags: optimization, regression

I'm facing the following problem. I have an unknown function with a very few known parameter-output sets according to the following:

```
  |param1  |param2  |output  |
--+--------+--------+--------+
1 | 0      | 0      | 43     |
2 | 0      | 100    | 36     |
3 | 500    | 100    | 66     |
4 | 1000   | 0      | 88     |
5 | 100    | 1000   | 61     |
6 | 500    | 500    | 78     |
```

I want to find the parameters at the optimum (maximum) of the function (with the additional condition that the sum of param1+param2 cannot be larger than 1000). How could that optimum calculated?

My idea is to find an approximation/candidate function based on the few data above, and then find it's optimum (with Nelder-Mead search or similar method). Is it a correct way? If so, what is the way to find the approximation function (by some regression, I guess, but this being an unsupervised task, how to set the power of the polynomial that describe the hyperplane in order not to be too high order)?

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: What does this have to do with functional analysis?